# Разработка GUI-приложений на PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt

У меня возник вопрос. Подойдёт ли библиотека PyQt5 в python для разработки GUI-приложений, для средних проектов или всё же брать серьёзные языки? Я выбрал другой язык - Си для создание приложений, но всё же мне интересно! Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Си не очень - он для библиотек, половина кода - распределение памяти. Бери хотяб си++.

Comment: Все таки плюсы - не самый простой в плане разработки язык. Кмк, лучше - C#. Да, у него монструозный оверхед в инструментах и библиотеке, зато интеграция с системным GUI макисмальная (это для винды). Если проекты подразумеваются на линукс или кроссплатформа, то можно посмотреть в сторону Lazarus - это такая OpenSource Delphi.